# RewriteRule not applyed in .htacces by dynamic string when match rules string word

Tags: .htaccess

i have write rule in `.htaccess` like

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-list-(.*) blog-single.php?slug=$1&id=$2
```

it means i go for url

```
www.mydomai.com/axz-any-post-list-7
```

its work file but in  `slug` if any word like `list` it make problem in RewriteRule Like:

```
www.mydomai.com/axz-any-list-post-list-7
```

if i have `slug` like `blog-single.php?slug=axz-any-list-post&id=7` then it broken **url**

so it any way to match only last word `list` in `.htaccess` befor `id` ?

Comment: does slug only contain letters not numbers?

Comment: slug contain letters and numbers only.